# C++ Macro Concatenation

Tags: c++, macros, concatenation

I'm having a little trouble understanding c++ macro concatenation.

At present, I have many classes sharing identically named static functions. For example:

```
ClassA::MyFunc1, ClassA::MyFunc2, ClassA::MyFunc3
ClassB::MyFunc1, ClassB::MyFunc2, ClassB::MyFunc3
ClassC::MyFunc1, ClassC::MyFunc2, ClassC::MyFunc3
```

I have a single interface that is used to call the static function based on a type. For example:

```
ClassInterface::MyFunc1(Type)
{
    switch (Type)
    {
        case TypeA:
        {
            ClassA::MyFunc1();
        }

        case TypeB:
        {
            ClassB::MyFunc1();
        }

        case TypeC:
        {
            ClassC::MyFunc1();
        }
    }
}
```

So that is for calling MyFunc1 by type through a single interface. So obviously if I have 50 classes and 50 static functions it is going to be frustrating writing them all each time.

I'm trying to write a macro to save myself a lot of time.

```
#define MyMacro(x)      \
    case TypeA:         \
    {                   \
        ClassA::##x;    \
    }                   \
                        \
    case TypeB:         \
    {                   \
        ClassB::##x;    \
    }                   \
                        \
    case TypeC:         \
    {                   \
        ClassC::##x;    \
    }
```

Then use it like so:

```
ClassInterface::MyFunc1(Type)
{
    switch (Type)
    {
        MyMacro(MyFunc1)
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error telling me x (inside the macro) is an undeclared identifier. Can anyone give me a hand here?

Using Visual Studio 2013...

error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'case'

error C2039: 'x' : is not a member of 'ClassA'

error C2039: 'x' : is not a member of 'ClassB'

error C2039: 'x' : is not a member of 'ClassC'

Comment: Please don't give assorted code blocks with an error description. Give a solid, complete [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with exact compiler errors.

Comment: Why would you do this? You've basically reimplemented virtual function dispatch using a `switch` statement and type codes?

Comment: I have good reasons for using this design and the context is completely irrelevant to the question, which is why I've simplified using this example.

Comment: Prefer not to use macros, especially in this manner.  There's got to be a better approach, such as templates or a change in design.  Macros are evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the concat operator, also you are not actually calling the functions.

Change your macro to the following:

```
//EDIT: you probably want some breaks in there
//      otherwise it could call all 3 functions
#define MyMacro(x)      \
case TypeA:         \
{                   \
    ClassA::x();    \
    break;          \
}                   \
                    \
case TypeB:         \
{                   \
    ClassB::x();    \
    break;          \
}                   \
                    \
case TypeC:         \
{                   \
    ClassC::x();    \
    break;          \
}
```

Comment: I added breaks, I'm guessing that was your intent in the first place.